# Unlink Ink File Picker on logout on iOS

Tags: ios, filepicker.io

Several iOS cloud storage frameworks like Dropbox and Box.net allow your app to unlink when a user logs out of your application, so when the next user logs in, they have to log back in to Ink. However, it seems like the user is still logged in between logouts. Nothing in the docs seem to indicate this functionality is available. Anyone come across it?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? Would like to force this as well as we have a situation where a device might be shared between different users.

Comment: I kinda-sorta did. I have a half-written solution forking Ink's picker code that enables a shared login manager that will track the cookies Ink sets up, and thus delete them when you want. It's not terribly elegant, but their library isn't structured in a way that makes this easy.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found a solution that works for my use case. It delinks the app from any services logged into via Filepicker by deleting all the saved cookies.

```
NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];
 for (NSHTTPCookie *cookie in cookies)
 {
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
 }
```

Comment: Be careful with this. To quote the docs: "As a rule, cookies are shared among all applications and are kept in sync across process boundaries." So you could be blowing away ALL your users cookies.